# Using Search Builder to search on a field with custom location gives DB error

Tags: search, location-type

On current CiviCRM demo site (4.6.10) if you

add a new location type, then populate a contact with an email address of that location type, then use Search builder to search for email address with location type, it gives error:

DB Error: syntax error

Comment: I think this is probably a bug.  It doesn't matter if you create a new location type or use a pre-populated one.  The sql has a column that doesn't exists and it's going against the wrong table.  Here's the sql:  SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) as sort_name FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE ( ( LOWER(`Home-location_type`.name) = '8' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY contact_a.id ORDER BY UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) asc [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'Home-location_type.name' in 'where clause'" Can you file a bug?

Comment: Thanks Paul-Tahoe, I've submitted as a bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17424

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, my comment probably should have been an answer…

I think this is probably a bug.

It doesn't matter if you create a new location type or use a pre-populated one. The sql has a column that doesn't exists and it's going against the wrong table. 
Here's the sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) as sort_name 
FROM   civicrm_contact contact_a 
WHERE  ( ( LOWER(Home-location_type.name) = '8' ) ) 
AND    (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY contact_a.id 
ORDER BY UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) asc
```

[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'Home-location_type.name' in 'where clause'"

AlanGallery submitted a bug see comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have some installations that work correctly and some that's don't work.

I made this patch, it's not a nice patch, becasuse it's not applied in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder, but temporally works

https://github.com/rubofvil/civicrm-core/commit/facfa396891229eb914397eb4920e75b6abff4a2